# How can I get a map of my plot of land for planning purposes?

Tags: soil, permaculture

I'm studying permaculture and I would like to design before I start doing anything. Is there any software that could give me a map of my plot of land, like from Google maps or from sigpac in Spain? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for an off-site resource. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/... for more information about this policy.

Comment: Your local authorities should have the data and could probably make a (paper) copy available to you.

Comment: You can ask questions like this on Software Recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any software that can do it for you but I have posted instructions on [designing your landscape with SketchUp](http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2013/09/how-to-draw-landscape-plan-with-sketchup.html) on my site.

My tutorial suggests you have a property survey of your home that you import into SketchUp, scale to the appropriate size and then trace over the features. I don't know about Spain but in the USA it's common to have a property survey drawing done before purchasing a home. The local government will also have tax maps on file for each property that show the property boundaries but with less detail than a property survey.

I've also done this using [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/) software. It's a desktop client for Google Maps that you install on your computer and has some more features. One of those features is a measuring tool. You can zoom into your home's satellite view and use the measuring tool to measure different features on your property then use those measurements to draw the property in SketchUp. It's not as precise as having a property survey but it gets you close if that's all you have.

As I mentioned, it doesn't automatically create your landscape map but it makes it easier for you to measure without actually going out to measure.

Answer (score 3):

Your asbuilt should show that.  If you did not build the house, or you just don't have it, it should be on file with the town with either the building inspector or the assessor.  You can scan that in to help start with a planning program.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that...it is true, a base plan for what you own should be in the city, county...state records somewhere.  Try your mortgage documents and if they aren't there, they should be.  Ask your realtor to dig them up...that's why they are paid such big bucks, grin!!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about) tools - if it doesn't currently include your garden then you can follow the [instructions](https://www.openstreetmap.org/welcome) on how to add it from the satellite imagery available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but! Doing the measuring yourself helps you to begin to really SEE your landscape.  Get a rolling tape...ruler?  About $30 and do it yourself.  If you want to design your own landscape this is the best way to start!  Also, in your mortgage documents, you should find an 'as-built' with property lines, orientation, septic, sewer lines and all buildings on your property when you purchased.  Get to know your property...where the wind prevails, big trees shade, neighbors, where you feel most private, what uses you'd like from your property (and are legal) such as a firepit, outdoor kitchen, garden walls, a vegetable garden, a hidden nook with a comfy bench, where you would need walkways, where the views from the windows of your home should be highlighted or downplayed or framed...when you are measuring this project becomes YOURS. You'll be taking mental pictures the entire time that you'll be able to pull up as you draw.  Get lots of 'bumwad' a transparent paper you can put over your BASE PLAN. Don't neglect drainage.  You should know where every drop of water on your site will go...if you have a flat topography, make elevations or depressions.  If you have steep slopes, figure out what they are and if you can live with them...or change them. The PROCESS is critical to getting a good design.  Don't make decisions, let your design come about by asking questions and make yourself give...at least 5 answers to each question.  You'll be surprised with what you discover...it is so very much fun!